# Adding of two confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, standard-error, error-propagation

Given two variables $\bar{A}$ with 95% confidence interval [$A_0$,$A_1$], and $\bar{X}$ with 95% confidence interval [$X_0$,$X_1$], how would one calculate the 95% confidence interval of a composite variable?

I.E. if $\bar{D}=\bar{A}-\bar{X}$, what would the confidence interval on $\bar{D}$ be? Keep in mind that $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{X}$ are calculated from two distributions which could be normal, but are not necessarily so.

I understand that in the case $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{A}$ are calculated from normal distributions that the confidence interval on $\bar{D}$ becomes $\bar{D}\pm\sqrt{\sigma_A^2+\sigma_X^2-2\sigma_{AX}}$, but I'm having a hard time understand how to apply that approach to distributions which are not symmetric(such as a binomial distribution).

Correction: $\bar{D}=\bar{D}\pm\sqrt{s_A^2+s_X^2-2 s_{A,X}}$,

Is there any generalized approach, or is it specific to the distributions used to calculate $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{A}$?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about the sample mean, then the distribution of the data can be hand waived away assuming you have enough data.

The confidence interval for the mean is a summary of the sampling distribution of the mean, which with enough data is asymptotically normal thanks to the central limit theorem (note that even in cases where the data distribution is heavily skewed, the [Berry-Essen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) bounds the difference between the true sampling distribution and the sampling distribution implied by the central limit theorem).

So to answer your question, if the sample statistic is the sample mean then you can just use what you've written (but make sure to use the standard errors and not the standard deviation, as you've written).

Comment: That helps a lot. How many samples do you need for this limit to become reasonably accurate? I am working on a model where the number of insects present is measured each day.

Given data {0,0,16,20,50,58,56,50,5,0,0}. And we see that that n=255 and that $\bar{X}$ is equal to 6.12 days. Given this is it appropriate to say that the confidence bands around $\bar{X}$ are approximately symmetric? Or how large does n need to be to suffice?